# Is there any conflict when adding an <iframe> whose content is HTML4 into a HTML5 web page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html4

I want to add an `<iframe>`, whose source is HTML 4, into a HTML 5 web page.
Are there any JavaScript or DOM conflicts that I should be aware of when doing so?

Will the browser encounter any errors when facing some special situation because the source types of the documents are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all, you can consider an iframe as a browser window open in your current page.
If the browser is able to properly render the HTML4 page on a normal tab, it will have no problem in an iframe as well (with some limitation which is not related to HTML4/5 anyway).

Answer (score 1):

No, there won't be any conflict, assuming both pages have a `<!DOCTYPE>`.  In fact, browsers don't even distinguish between HTML 4 and HTML 5.

More specifically, without a DOCTYPE a page will be rendered in quirks mode which can result in several major differences.  In Internet Explorer, for example, the page will be rendered by an older implementation of the engine, resulting in several DOM and JS (as well as layout differences).  If you're using JS to manipulate one frame from the other, then there's a chance something doesn't work the way you expect it to — the way it would in standards mode.

TLDR; use a `<!DOCTYPE>`.

Comment: If one document is HTML 5 then it won't have a DTD. In HTML 5, the Doctype declaration is replaced by a magic string that triggers Standards mode.

Comment: @Quentin: `<!DOCTYPE html>` isn't a DTD? Perhaps I just have my terminology mixed up.

Comment: @Andy E: You could say it's a doctype *declaration*, but it does not reference any DTD (doctype *definition*) file, because HTML5 doesn't have such a definition.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, which has different rendering and JS support depending on the doctype, if the framed page is on the same domain and the HTML5 parent calls methods on elements in the framed page, the available methods will be limited to the old stuff. For example, addEventListener() probably won't be available on window, document and elements in the framed page.

So, just because the HTML5 page has support for all kinds of new stuff, that doesn't mean you can use its environment to call those functions on objects in a non-HTML5, framed page.

Comment: IE doesn't have *'different rendering and JS support depending on the doctype'*.  Rather, no doctype will trigger quirks mode (IE 5.5) and *any* doctype will trigger standards mode.  For instance, `<!DOCTYPE Shadow2531>` will still trigger standards mode.

Comment: @AndyE In IE9+, "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" was supposed to trigger super standards mode (called IE9 standards mode for IE9) where all the new stuff (addEventListener, getElementById fixes, <video>, <audio> etc.) works. But, another doctype that triggers standards mode would just trigger regular standards mode (IE8 standards mode) where that stuff wasn't supported. I remember reading this on the IE blog. But, I just checked in IE9 on Win7 and it appears the IE team decided not to go that route and it makes all the new stuff work in what was then called regular standards mode. So, my mistake.